# Caffe's label on ILSVRC dataset

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I found that label defined in `synset_words.txt` is different from in `det_synset_words.txt`. What if I want to use one of the target classes available in `det_synset_words.txt`, but not available in `synset_words.txt`, what should I do? What is the difference between the two files, anyway? If I would just use one of them interchangeably, it simply won't work as their numbers of output are different i.e. one has 1000 (`synset_words.txt`) and the other contains 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1000 classes defined in `synset_words.txt` are the classes used for image classification competition: that is, predicting a single label per input image.
On the other hand, `det_synset_words.txt` lists the 200 categories used for the detection competition, that is, predicting **bounding boxes** as well as class label for each instance of the 200 classes in a given image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But then, how to find a Caffe model for using with that "det_synset_words.txt" label? Any web pointer for that pre-trained model that has been trained with 200 number of output  is helpful.

Comment: @if you find such models, they will usually be for detection and not classification. my current personal favorite is [SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) that you might want to explore

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. The only that I found it weird in the ILSVRC dataset "package" is that it included that detection stuff which is not related to the accompanied Caffe reference model. I mean can be misleading for some people.